# $T^n - T + 1$ is separable over a field $k$ unless $\mathrm{char}(k)$ divides $n^n - (n - 1)^{n - 1}$ for all $n \geq 2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

I am trying to prove the statement:

> $T^n - T + 1$ is separable over a field $k$ unless $\mathrm{char}(k)$ divides $n^n - (n - 1)^{n - 1}$ for all $n \geq 2$

My first thought was to prove this using induction on $n$. For $n = 2$, $T^2 - T + 1 = \frac{(2T - 1)}{4} (2T - 1) + \frac{3}{4}$ and thus $T^2 - T + 1$ and its derivative are coprime unless $3 \equiv 0$, i.e. $\mathrm{char}(K) = 3$. (What about when $char(K) = 4$, may we conclude directly that $T^2 - T + 1$ and its derivative are coprime?)

Now, for a general $n \geq 2$, similar reasoning leads to the following:

$T^n - T +1 = (nT^{n-1} - 1)(\frac{T}{n} - \frac{n - 1}{n^2 T^{n - 2}}) + \frac{n^2 T^{n - 2} - n + 1}{n^2 T^{n - 2}}$.

Then $T^n - T +1$ and its derivative would be coprime unless $n - 1 \equiv n^2 T^{n-2}$, which doesn't seem related to what I have to prove.

I'd appreciate any remarks or different methods to prove the statement.

Comment: $\mathrm{char}(K)$ is prime or zero, so it can't be $4$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh right, but what about when the characteristic is 2?

Comment: When $f(t)=t^2-t+1$ and and $\mathrm{char}(k)=2$, then $f'(t)=-1$, so $f'(t)$ and $f(t)$ are trivially relatively prime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Let $f(T)=T^n-T+1$. Then $f'(T)=nT^{n-1}-1$ and $$nf(T)-Tf'(T)=n(T^n-T+1)-T(nT^{n-1}-1)=-(n-1)T+n$$

So what can be the GCD of $f(T)$ and $f'(T)$?

Comment: I don't really see what you are getting at. Would this mean that the gcd of $f(T)$ and $f'(T)$ must divide both 1 and $n - 1$? Then this would mean that $f(T)$ is separable, but I am still confused about the bit "... unless $char(k)$ divides $n^n - (n - 1)^{n-1}$".

Comment: No, it means the $GCD$ must be a factor of $-(n-1)T+n$. Thus the GCD of $f(T)$ and $f'(T)$ is not $1$ if and only if $n(n-1)^{-1}$ is a root of $f(T)$ and $f'(T)$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the equivalence between the gcd not being equal to 1 and the fact that $n(n - 1)^{-1}$ is a root of $f(T)$ and $f'(T)$?

Comment: Thomas calculates a polynomial $g$ that is a common factor of $f$ and $f'$, so each root of $g$ is a root of $f$ and also one of $f'$. In the case of character $0$ this is not the case but you can find those characteristics by substituting $\frac{n}{n-1}$ in both $f$ and $f'$

Comment: @BogaertsMarc Ok so let's denote $-(n - 1)T +n$ as $g(T)$. A gcd of $f(T)$ and $f'(T)$ (which from now on, I will refer to as "the gcd") must divide $g(T)$. The gcd is not equal to 1 iff $g(T) = 0$, i.e. if $\frac{n}{n - 1}$ is a root of $g(T)$. But then also $\frac{n}{n - 1}$ is a root of the gcd (this is the part where I got stuck previously), and thus a root of $f(T)$ and $f'(T)$. Substituting $T$ for this fraction in both $f(T)$ and $f'(T)$ yields the result. Thank you both for the help!